# Defined coloring of dynamic diagrams

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to color the diagrams "Result" automatically according to the specified color.

The diagrams should be based entirely on the arrays and adapt themselves dynamically.

For example, if I add "Spain", Spain should be added in the color green in all charts, Spain should also be added in the color green.

The chart type varies and is therefore not limited to a barchart and linechart. However, it does not matter whether existing charts are colored or new ones created.

I created the following code using ChatGPT. However, this is limited to non-dynamic areas.

I had hoped that all diagrams would be formatted accordingly. Unfortunately, this was only the case for charts that I did not create using Excel's name manager.

```vb
Sub FormatDiagramAsCellValue_tryA()
Dim targetNameRange As Range
Dim targetColorCodeRange As Range
Dim selectedChart As chartObject
Dim series As series
Dim cellName As Range
Dim cellColor As Range
Dim targetName As String
Dim targetColorCode As String
Dim chartName As String

' Disable updates to speed up execution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Prompt for the range of names
On Error Resume Next
Set targetNameRange = Application.InputBox("Select range for names", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if the user canceled the input or selected an invalid range
If targetNameRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Canceled or invalid range selected for names.", vbExclamation
    GoTo CleanupAndExit
End If

' Prompt for the range of color codes
On Error Resume Next
Set targetColorCodeRange = Application.InputBox("Select range for color codes", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if the user canceled the input or selected an invalid range
If targetColorCodeRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Canceled or invalid range selected for color codes.", vbExclamation
    GoTo CleanupAndExit
End If

' Ask the user for the chart name
chartName = InputBox("Enter the chart name:")

' Check if a chart with the specified name exists
On Error Resume Next
Set selectedChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName)
On Error GoTo 0
If selectedChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Chart with the specified name not found.", vbExclamation
    GoTo CleanupAndExit
End If

' Iterate through all cells in the range for names
For Each cellName In targetNameRange
    ' Check if the cell is not empty
    If Not IsEmpty(cellName.Value) Then
        ' Get the target name and target color code
        targetName = cellName.Value
        ' Search for the target color code in the corresponding row in the range for color codes
        On Error Resume Next
        Set cellColor = targetColorCodeRange.Cells(cellName.Row - targetColorCodeRange.Rows(1).Row + 1, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Check if the target color code was found
        If Not cellColor Is Nothing Then
            ' Get the target color code
            targetColorCode = cellColor.Value
            ' Iterate through all data series in the selected chart
            For Each series In selectedChart.chart.SeriesCollection
                ' Check if the name of the data series matches the target name
                If InStr(1, series.Name, targetName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    ' Set the fill color and line color of the data series according to the color code
                    series.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGBFromHex(targetColorCode)
                    series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Black
                    series.Format.Line.Weight = 1 ' Width of the line
                End If
            Next series
        End If
    End If
Next cellName

CleanupAndExit:
    ' Enable updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function RGBFromHex(hexCode As String) As Long
    ' Convert a hex code to an RGB color
    Dim red As Integer, green As Integer, blue As Integer
    red = CLng("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 2, 2))
    green = CLng("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 4, 2))
    blue = CLng("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 6, 2))
    RGBFromHex = RGB(red, green, blue)
End Function
```